# A good Clojure set up on a Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, clojure, workflow, leiningen

I have done a lot of research on clojure programming. I would like to have a clean set up where I can easily see and access all of my projects, quickly test/modify them in a REPL, and package them once they are complete so that I can call them from the command line.

Through multiple recommendations, I currently have a confusing mosh of CCW in Eclipse, Leiningen, maven, and SublimeREPL. Experienced Clojurians, especially mac users, what are the tools that you use?

I would particularly appreciate a step-by-step account of working on a project, such as how you have your windows set up and how to quickly load files into a REPL.

On a related note, whenever I hit an error while using the REPL in eclipse, I have to close it and restart it every time. If I try to continue, all I get is an 'unhandled REPL exception'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Clojure development on the Mac, I use Sam Aaron's excellent "curated emacs experience", Emacs-live. It's a set of customisations to emacs which were put together primarily to turn emacs into a live music performance tool (with Overtone, a Clojure library for making music). However as a side effect of this it looks beautiful, and comes with a neat Clojure configuration. I use it for all my Clojure development work on the Mac.

To get up and running with Clojure emacs-live:

1. **Install the latest emacs**. You can get Mac binaries at http://emacsformacosx.com/
2. **Install emacs-live.** Easiest way is to run the "brogrammer" installation script

   ```
   bash <(curl -fksSL https://raw.github.com/overtone/emacs-live/master/installer/install-emacs-live.sh)
   ```

   You can also do a manual installation following instructions at the github repo https://github.com/overtone/emacs-live
3. **Install leiningen.** Sounds like you have that already. If not, just do `brew install leiningen` (you have homebrew right? If not, you can follow the instructions at the leiningen repo https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen).

Now for your real questions....

1. **How do I easily see and access all of my projects?**
   Emacs has built in bookmarking - I just bookmark the root directory of each project so I can jump to it quickly. 
   To bookmark a file or folder use the key command `C-x r m`, and to see the bookmark list use `C-x r l`. You can browse around directories in emacs using a text-based directory browser (called `dired`) which is accessible by the key command `C-x d`.
2. **How do I quickly test/modify my projects in a REPL?**
   Emacs-live has nrepl.el included. This means that from any clojure source file you can invoke the command `M-x nrepl-jack-in`. This will give you a repl which you can use to test your program. Any `.clj` file loaded in emacs will put you into clojure-mode. Some useful commands in clojure-mode are:

   - `C-c M-n` (from source file) switch namespace of repl to namespace of current source file
   - `C-c C-k` evaluate current buffer (file)
   - `C-x C-e` evaluate last s-expression
   - `M-.` jump to definition
   - `M-,` jump back
3. **How do I have my windows set up?**
   I usually have a horizontal split (`C-x 2`), with a repl in the lower window and the source file I'm currently working with in the top window. I'll switch between open source files in the top window using `C-x b` (switch buffer). Works for me.
4. **How do I package them once they are complete?**
   Use `lein uberjar` from a command line (`M-x eshell`) to package up the project and its dependencies.

Note: 
I've used the standard shorthand for expressing keyboard shortcuts in emacs above. It's a bit archaic, but on the Mac, as standard, `C` is mapped to the control key, and `M` is mapped to the alt key.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this was exactly the kind of detail I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

My personal setup is:

- Lein (installed via Homebrew)
- VIM (Vim-Clojure, Powerline, vim-fugitive plugins)

That is, easy and simple! And I worked in Clojure professionally for one year.

But you might also want to have a look at: [LightTable](http://www.lighttable.com/) and [NightCode](http://nightcode.info/). Both look interesting approaches to Clojure development.

Comment: Agreed - LightTable has awesome potential. I'm especially looking forward to the beta release which will open it up to user plugins.